# mysql select by filter

Tags: php, filter

Whats Wrong with my code its Returning 0

```
            $query = "SELECT cid, COUNT(cid) FROM topic_reply WHERE cid='$forum_id'";    
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());    
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "There are ". $row['COUNT(cid)'] ." ". $row['cid'] ." items.";
            echo "<br />";
        }
```

I try all possible codes to display the results by its returng 0.. but if i remove the WHERE filter its returns all rows what happened? hehe

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish but I think it might be a count of a particular cid:

```
$query = "SELECT cid, COUNT(cid) FROM topic_reply WHERE cid='$forum_id' GROUP BY cid";
```

Comment: $forum=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum WHERE pid='$cat_id'");
while($forumrow = mysql_fetch_array($forum))
{
// code here
$threadcount=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE parent='$forum_id'");
$thread_count_rows = mysql_num_rows($threadcount);
while($threadrow = mysql_fetch_array($threadcount)) 
 {
   $parent_id = $threadrow['id'];    
 }  
  // some more code here
Continue Below

Comment: $query = "SELECT cid, COUNT(cid) FROM topic_reply WHERE cid='$forum_id' GROUP BY cid";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
 $temp1 = $row['COUNT(cid)'];  
 if($temp1==1) { echo '<img StarImage_1.png>'; }
 elseif($temp1>=10) { echo '<img StarImage_2.png>'; }
// and so on}
}